# PowerBI - How to highlight rows in a table based on if a value is within a range

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

- I want to highlight the rows the where the** W.Disc** rate is not within the range of the **StretchPrice(Disc-%)** value and the **FloorPrice(Disc-%). **

Any number that is not within the range, I would like to high light red somehow. Thank you!

[Picture of table in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybPqP.png)

I have to tried to employ conditional formatting, but I don't think this was possible, due to the fact that in Conditional Formatting you can only specify 1 field/column to base the rule on. In this instance I would be basing the conditions on 2 fields/columns, specifically if the W.Disc is within the range of two fields/columns. Perhaphs I could make a measure that would highlight any W.Disc number that is not within the range and apply it in that way? Any help would be appreciated.

I just tried to include the following measure, but the measure does not seem to work. Any idea as to why? Thank you!

Test range = IF(
[W.Discount% Products] > MAX('New Sheet'[StretchedPrice(Disc-%)]) && < MIN('New Sheet'[FloorPrice(Disc-%)]), "Within Range", "Outside Range")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a Calculated Column or Measure which has the multiple conditions you are after. Then in Conditional Formatting, use that as your Field.

Including your expression:

```
Test range = IF( 
  [W.Discount% Products] >= MAX('New Sheet'[StretchedPrice(Disc-%)]) &&
  [W.Discount% Products] <= MIN('New Sheet'[FloorPrice(Disc-%)]),
  "Within Range",
  "Outside Range"
)
```

Follow-up to your question in the comments about determining the amount outside of the range:

```
Outside Range by =
  var rngStart = MAX('New Sheet'[StretchedPrice(Disc-%)])
  var rngEnd = MIN('New Sheet'[FloorPrice(Disc-%)])
  var me = [W.Discount% Products]
  RETURN SWITCH( TRUE(),
    me < rngStart, me - rngStart, // if you want positive then rngStart - me
    me > rngEnd, me - rngEnd
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. That's kind what I thought. To be completely honest this is my first proper PowerBI Dashboard I am creating. Which functions would work best for this purpose? Would a multi-IF function work well here, or do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: I just tried to following but it does not work unfortunately. Can you see the error?

Test range = IF(
    [W.Discount% Products] > MAX('New Sheet'[StretchedPrice(Disc-%)]) && < MIN('New Sheet'[FloorPrice(Disc-%)]), "Within Range", "Outside Range")

Comment: It needs to be IF( x >= y && x <= z, ... - I've updated the answer above with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help before. 
If the W.Disc% is outside the range and I want to calculate the exact difference until the number is within range - would that be possible? So if the W.Disc% is 56% and the lower limit is 60%, then I would like it to display the value 4%. (or -4%, doesn't mattet)
Once again, you are a huge life savour. Can't express my thanks enough.

Comment: Included in the answer above.